# is it possible to reverse the output of "filters" command?

Tags: text-processing, games

On Linux, the [`filters`](http://kitenet.net/~joey/code/filters/) package could be great fun, really. Is there any way to reverse the output to what it basically was?

```
echo "Hi. My name is Chirp Chirp" | ky00te
Hy. My name ys Chyrrp Chyrrp
```

Is it possible to reverse "*Hy. My name ys Chyrrp Chyrrp*" (back) to "*Hi. My name is Chirp Chirp*", knowing that the `ky00te` filter was used?

Comment: If the transformation is both reversible and known then you can write a program which does the reversal.

Answer (score 1):

`ky00te` at least is not reversible:

```
$ echo is a | ky00te
yssa
$ echo is the | ky00te
yssa
```